# Alternative to Lookup() function in SSRS

Tags: function, reporting-services, report, lookup

Currently I'm trying to display custom data per a unique key, like a person ID. For example, if I select an ID from a dropdown (a parameter), the data should be tailored to that ID. If I change the ID, the data should change with it. However, I'm using a Lookup() function for now since my report only returns the first row of data even if I change the ID. I've tried filters but haven't had luck. There should be an alternative to the lookup function. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the best way to accomplish this is with cascading parameters.
See [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)
In short, have your initial visible parameter drive a lookup query, the values of which are used a parameters for the main query.